# DoTween repeatType.yoyo not working inside Sequence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

I am using DoTween and have a `Sequence` to scale a button from 0 to 1 and then pulse the scale from 1 to 1.25 looped.

My problem is that the loop inside the `Sequence` does not work. It will go to scale 1 and then to 1.25 but stop there.

If I just run the loop outside the `Sequence` it works fine.

```
DOTween.Sequence()
   .Append(playButton.transform.DOScale(new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1), 1f).SetEase(Ease.OutBack))
   .Append(playButton.transform.DOScale(new Vector3(1.25f, 1.5f, 1), 1f).SetEase(Ease.Linear).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo))
   .SetAutoKill(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Infinite loops will not be applied if the tween is inside a Sequence.

You could set the loop count to a large value. Or use `AppendCallback` and start the infinite loop from there.

Similar Questions:

1. https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/issues/92
2. https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween/issues/220